# Underscore in Where clause yields unexpected result, why?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016, sql-like

I want to find all tables starting with `TB_`, hence I've wrote following script:

```
select *
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
where TABLE_NAME like 'TB_%'
```

To my surprise I got following result:

```
TB103_xxx
TB037_bbb
TB104_ccc
```

I'm curious why?

Answer (score 8):

It means any single character in combination with a like. See

[MSDN - LIKE (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

- `%` - Any string of zero or more characters.
- `_` - Any single character. `_a` will match `aa`, `ba` etc.
- `[ ]` - Any single character within the specified range ([a-f]) or set ([abcdef]).
- `[^]` - Any single character not within the specified range ([^a-f]) or set ([^abcdef]).

You could use `[_]` to match a underscore, so `like 'TB[_]%'`

Or you could use `LIKE 'TB\_%' ESCAPE '\'.` (thanks to Jeroen Mostert)

Comment: wow, you're fast, just found it
The underscore represents a single character. For example, the following statement returns the customers where the second character is the letter u:

Comment: But, if you are searching for the actual underscore or percent character within a string you should use the T-SQL escape sequence [%] or [_].

Comment: @krul - You need to escape (`[_]`) the underscore to get result with underscore

Comment: Aside from `[_]` you can also escape explicitly with `LIKE 'TB\_%' ESCAPE '\'`. Note that there is no default escape character if no `ESCAPE` clause is provided.

Comment: @JeroenMostert thanks for pointing that out; what a weird syntax, never saw it before

Answer (score 4):

This is why because you used the underscore (_) symbol. It means the string Allows you to match on a single character. 
Check this [SQL LIKE Operator](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp)

Better you should use `WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE 'TB[_]%'` or `WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE 'TB\_%'`

`%` - The percent sign represents zero, one, or multiple characters.

`_` - The underscore represents a single character.

`[]` - Any single character within the specified range ([a-f]) or set ([abcdef]).

`[^]` - Any single character not within the specified range ([^a-f]) or set ([^abcdef]).

Here is some examples

```sql
WHERE CustomerName LIKE 'a%'           Finds any values that start with "a"
WHERE CustomerName LIKE '%a'           Finds any values that end with "a"
WHERE CustomerName LIKE '%or%'         Finds any values that have "or" in any position
WHERE CustomerName LIKE '_r%'          Finds any values that have "r" in the second position
WHERE CustomerName LIKE 'a_%'          Finds any values that start with "a" and are at least 2 characters in length
WHERE CustomerName LIKE 'a%o'          Finds any values that start with "a" and ends with "o"
WHERE CustomerName LIKE '[a-e]arsen'   Finds any values that end with "arsen" and starting with any single character between "a" and "e"
WHERE CustomerName LIKE '[^a-e]arsen'  Finds any values that end with "arsen" and starting with any single character isn't between "a" and "e".
```